# Pyplot 3D subplots prevent clipping

Tags: python, matplotlib

I seek to reduce distance between subplots, but that makes their invisible axis planes clip over each other. How can I prevent this?

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cs = np.cos(2*np.pi * np.linspace(0, 1, 128, 0))
sn = np.sin(2*np.pi * np.linspace(0, 1, 128, 0))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')

for ax in (ax0, ax1):
    ax.plot(cs, sn)
    for anm in ('x', 'y', 'z'):
        getattr(ax, f'set_{anm}ticks')([])
        getattr(ax, f'w_{anm}axis').set_pane_color((1, 1, 1, 0))
        getattr(ax, f'w_{anm}axis').line.set_color((1, 1, 1, 0))
        getattr(ax, f'set_{anm}margin')(0)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=1, bottom=0, right=1, left=0, hspace=-.5, wspace=-.5)
```

Comment: You can make the background transparent with `ax1.patch.set_alpha(0.)`.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen Perfect, thank you. Feel free to post as the answer.